# FreeBSD equivalent of Linux's "xt_bpf" filtering module

Tags: linux, iptables, freebsd, ipfw

In Linux 3.9 there's a packet filter module called `xt_bpf` that can take compiled BPF bytecode and use it directly in an iptables rule.

Is there any equivalent for FreeBSD's `ipfw` system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try netgraph node **ng_bpf**.

Comment: thanks - looks useful.  Do you happen to have any pointers on how to integrate `netgraph` with `ipfw`?

Comment: You need to use ng_ipfw. Alas i have no exapmles right now.

Comment: thanks anyway - unfortunately the documentation for `ng_ipfw` appears to be very poor :(